# design options to query from two different oracle databases

Tags: oracle, union

We have a transactional database with just 2 weeks of data and another archive database which holds data older than 2 weeks. Both DBs share the same schema structure and are in separate servers. We have a reporting application which queries data from both these databases where the user selects which database he wants to query by using a dropdown selection. In order to improve user experience we are thinking to do away with the dropdown selection by making the DB selection transparent in the background. Below are the few options we had in mind

1. Use UNION for the 2 select queries via DB links
2. Query DB1 first and if no records query DB2

Since the data volume is more we are apprehensive about our choices.
Appreciate if anyone has any other suggestions on how to approach this.

Comment: If you're going to combine the data sets, you almost certainly want to use a `UNION ALL` rather than a `UNION`.  Unless you really, really need to do the extra sort to remove duplicates.  Can you rethink the approach and keep all the data in a single partitioned table?  Do the queries have a predicate on the date that indicates whether they want old or new data?

Comment: thanks @JustinCave, table partitioning not an option due to licensing challenge. Out query simply has the date range which could fall either in one database or the other or in both.

Comment: OK, partitioning is out.  Can you keep all the data in a single database?  Do you want to do frequent full table scans on the table with the newer data?  Or do you want your queries to use an index on the date column?

Comment: Separate archive DB came in to the picture since we wanted to keep the live DB thin for "transactional" performance reasons. So there is no question of keeping both in one. And our query will always have the indexed date column in the where clause.

Comment: Why does a separate database improve performance?  If your queries are accessing the data via an index, the amount of data in the table should have extremely little impact on query performance.  Even if you wanted to have separate tables for some reason, what benefit do you get from putting those tables on separate databases?  Is there a lot of reporting that only ever queries the archived data that can be offloaded to free up resources on the transactional database?

Comment: yep, we wanted to avoid running reporting kind of queries in transactional database. By the way our transactional database is replicated via ADG which is where our reporting application connects to.

Comment: What is ADG?  Active Data Guard?  If your reporting database is maintained via Active Data Guard, wouldn't the table in the reporting database have all the data?  So reporting queries could always query just the reporting database table and ignore the source database entirely?

Comment: our setup, SOURCE->ADG->ARCHIVE->HISTORY. For majority of reporting users only ADG and ARCHIVE are exposed via our reporting application. SOURCE and ADG maintain the same data retention period of 2 weeks which is obvious. SOURCE access is made available only for critical support users in case of any issues in ADG replication.

Comment: I think I'm more confused.  Are you saying that you really have 4 databases, not just 2?  Does ADG stand for Active Data Guard?  Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular opinion, the best two choices are:

- always give the user the data newer than a relative date (e.g. the last three months of data).
- always give the user the last n data (e.g. the newest 250 rows).

Give all data will be inefficient when you have a big dataset.

But if you want to strengthen the autonomy and protect the user's work (two important design principles in user interfaces) then you must let the user configure the relative time or the number of data items desired. Or you can also let the user explore all/older data in particular situation (e.g. using a special window, a pagination system, a particular interface or a completly new use case).

Let's see two examples. (I assume that user is querying the server with newest data and OLD is the name of the dblink you use to reference the server with the data older than two weeks. I also assume that the target table is named DATATABLE and the column with the date is called DATADATE).

To retrieve the last three months (first choice):

```
SELECT * FROM DATATABLE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM DATATABLE@OLD WHERE MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, DATADATE) >= 3;
```

And, to retrieve the last 250 rows (second choice):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM DATATABLE ORDER BY DATADATE DESC) 
  WHERE ROWNUM <= 250;
UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT * FROM DATATABLE@OLD ORDER BY DATADATE DESC)
  WHERE ROWNUM <= (250 - (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATATABLE));
```

Comment: First choice will be very fast if you maintain an index on DATADATE (it will use a range scan over the index).

Comment: Second choice will be also fast if you maintain the the same index on DATADATE (it will use the index when ordering).